Boundary of a finite union of balls in $\mathbb R^n$
Let $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open set that is a finite union of open balls (in Euclidean metric).
I want o prove the following
Claim. There exists an open set $W\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ such that $W\cap\partial U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n-1}$.
My idea is to prove that $\partial U$ can be written as $\partial U=\bigcup_{i=1}^k M_i$, where each $M_i$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional compact manifold with boundary and $\operatorname{Int} M_i$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n-1}$, and also $\operatorname{Int}M_i\cap M_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$ (interior stands for manifold interior not interior in $\mathbb R^n$). Then I could define $W=\mathbb R^n\setminus \bigcup_{j\neq i}M_j$ for some $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and $W\cap \partial U= \operatorname{Int}M_i$. However, I don't know how to prove that such decomposition exists (I tried induction but failed).
I believe that the claim is not true for arbitrary open sets $U$ (because of Lakes of Wada counterexample)
Here
Topological classification of a finite union of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$
I found the information that a finite union of open balls in $\mathbb R^n$
is tame and the appropriate manifold $\overline{M}$
is homeomorphic to a piecewise-linear submanifold in $\mathbb R^n$. I don't know if that may be useful.
Edit summary. Originally I asked about balls in arbitrary metric that induces natural topology, but (because of counterexamples) now it is changed to Euclidean metric. I wonder if we can generalize to a metric coming from the norm.

It is false even for $n=1$ and a single open ball (the boundary can be the Cantor set).

@MoisheKohan How? As far as I know the boundary of an open ball in $\mathbb R$ has exactly two points. Can we choose a metric so that it is different?

Yes, the metric is not  intrinsic but defines the standard topology. For every intrinsic metric on $\mathbb R$, metric balls are indeed intervals.  I will add an answer later on.

Then I believe that the claim holds at least for Euclidean metric. I edited the question.

Oh, that's completely different.

I will write a proof when I have a bit more time.
